# Formula for the differential of a left-invariant 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-forms

I am currently working through the first volume of spivak's differential geometry and am currently on the chapter on Lie groups. After showing that the differential of a left invariant form is itself left invariant, he then does the following

$d\omega(\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y})=\tilde{X}(\omega(\tilde{Y}))-\tilde{Y}(\omega(\tilde{X}))-\omega([\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}])$
$=-\omega([\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}])$

to demonstrate a simplified formula for the differential of a 1-form.

Here, $\omega$ is left-invariant 1-form and $\tilde{X}$, $\tilde{Y}$ are left-invariant vector fields.

While I can understand the first equality (it is simply the coordinate-free formula for a 1-form), I can't understand what motivates the second equality.

Is there a reason the two left terms should be equal or is it that they both go to zero for left-invariant vector fields?

Comment: If $\omega$ is left invariant and $X$ and $Y$ are left invariant, then $\omega(X)$ and $\omega(Y)$ are constant function. Thus, $X\cdot \omega(Y)$ and $Y\cdot \omega(X)$ are zero.

Comment: @DIdier_ why are they constant?

Comment: This is a direct computation. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are left invariant vector fields, and that $\omega$ is a left invariant $1$-form. Then
\begin{align}
\forall g \in G,~ X(g) &= g\cdot X(e) \\
Y(g)& = g\cdot Y(e) \\
\omega_g(X(g))&= \omega_e(g^{-1}X(g)) = \omega_e(g^{-1}g\cdot X_e) = \omega_e(X_e)\\
\omega_g(Y(g))&= \omega_e(g^{-1}Y(g)) = \omega_e(g^{-1}g\cdot Y_e) = \omega_e(Y_e)
\end{align}

Then, $g \mapsto \omega(X) (g)$ and $g\mapsto \omega(Y)(g)$ are constant functions, and thus, $X\cdot \omega(Y) = Y\cdot\omega(X) = 0$. Hence
$$
\mathrm{d}\omega(X,Y) = X\cdot \omega(Y) - Y\cdot \omega(X) - \omega\left([X,Y]\right) = - \omega([X,Y])
$$

Comment: I get it now, thank you.